# Bootstrap 5 Grid System ( 5 cards at right and 1 grid as a menu )

Tags: html

[image: 6 equal column, 5 cards and the left one is different]

I want to achieve the result like the image, 5 columns are cards and one is like menu in the same page (at the same grid system ) with bootstrap 5. I know how to achieve it with css flexbox, I want to achieve it with bs5 grid system. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Use class `row` to make one row at the beginning. Separate your row with `col-x`.

For further explanation, please refer to the bootstrap documentation: [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

Here is an example:

```css
.card-black{
height: 200px;
background-color: black;
}

.card-yellow{
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
}

.card-green{
height: 100px;
background-color: green;
}

.card-red{
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}

.card-blue{
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
}

.card-purple{
height: 100px;
background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 card-black"></div>
  <div class="col-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 card-yellow"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-red"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-purple"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-blue"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-yellow"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-green"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-blue"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-yellow"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-red"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-purple"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-red"></div>
      <div class="col-2 card-purple"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The intention is to create 5 cards in the right. not 6 cards! thanks